# Is this not a tuple?

Tags: python, django, tuples

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. My error is: ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/ '**CategoryAdmin.fields**' must be a list or tuple.

Isn't the CategoryAdmin.fields a tuple? Am I reading this wrong?

**admin.py** 
..

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title')
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'creation_date')

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('author', 'title', 'content')
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'creation_date')

admin.site.register(
    models.Category, 
    CategoryAdmin
)
admin.site.register(
    models.Post, 
    PostAdmin
)
```

Comment: 5 thousand 1 line answers to follow...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is not. You need to add a comma:

```
fields = ('title',)
```

It is the *comma* that makes this a tuple. The parenthesis are really just optional here:

```
>>> ('title')
'title'
>>> 'title',
('title',)
```

The parenthesis are of course still a good idea, with parenthesis tuples are easier to spot visually, and the parenthesis distinguish the tuple in a function call from other parameters (`foo(('title',), 'bar')` is different from `foo('title', 'bar')`).

Comment: It's the comma that makes two-tuples too.  `a = 'foo','bar'` -- The parens are only to avoid syntax ambiguities in other places (like function calls)

Comment: @mgilson The parenthesis also make tuples a tad more readable IMO

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
fields = ('title', )
```

Example:

```
In [64]: type(('title'))
Out[64]: str

In [65]: type(('title', ))
Out[65]: tuple
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace it with this:

```
fields = ('title', )
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a comma after title:

```
fields = ('title',)
```